# look for common entries in two data frames

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, summarize

```
df1:
 state group species
1 CA 2 cat, dog, chicken, mouse
2 CA 1 cat
3 NV 1 dog, chicken
4 NV 2 chicken
5 WA 1 chicken, rat, mouse, lion
6 WA 2 dog, cat
7 WA 3 dog, chicken
8 WA 4 cat, chicken

df2:
 state special_species
1 CA cat
2 CA chicken
3 CA mouse
4 WA cat
5 WA chicken
6 NV dog
```

I'm interested in determining which of the special_species from `df2` are present in `df1`. I'd like a new dataframe that has the `state`, `group`, and the `special_species`.

Anticipated output:

```
state group special_species
CA 2 cat, chicken, mouse
CA 1 cat
NV 1 dog
NV 2 NA
WA 1 chicken
WA 2 cat
WA 3 chicken
WA 4 cat, chicken
```

Comment: Can you show us what you anticipate the output to be? This would help to close the loop and confirm understanding of the question you ask.

Comment: just updated the post with my anticipated output - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This was harder than I thought it would be. I think the following works, but hopefully someone can come up with something prettier.

First we make some data to work with (please do this yourself in the future), which I include if anyone else wants a go:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tribble(
  ~state, ~group, ~species,
  "CA", 2, "cat, dog, chicken, mouse",
  "CA", 1, "cat",
  "NV", 1, "dog, chicken",
  "NV", 2, "chicken",
  "WA", 1, "chicken, rat, mouse, lion",
  "WA", 2, "dog, cat",
  "WA", 3, "dog, chicken",
  "WA", 4, "cat, chicken")

df2 <- tribble(
  ~state, ~special_species,
  "CA", "cat",
  "CA", "chicken",
  "CA", "mouse",
  "WA", "cat",
  "WA", "chicken",
  "NV", "dog")
```

Then the solution is:

```r
df1 %>% 
  separate_rows(species) %>% 
  full_join(df2, on = "state") %>%
  filter(species == special_species) %>%
  group_by(state, group) %>%
  summarise(species = paste(special_species, collapse = ", ")) %>%
  full_join(df1, by = c("state" = "state", "group" = "group")) %>%
  select(state, group, special_species = species.x) %>%
  arrange(state)
#> Joining, by = "state"
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   state [3]
#>   state group special_species    
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr>              
#> 1 CA        1 cat                
#> 2 CA        2 cat, chicken, mouse
#> 3 NV        1 dog                
#> 4 NV        2 <NA>               
#> 5 WA        1 chicken            
#> 6 WA        2 cat                
#> 7 WA        3 chicken            
#> 8 WA        4 cat, chicken
```

The code can be significantly simplified if you would accept the desired output in slightly different format, e.g. the following is correct save the `NA`:

```r
df1 %>% 
  separate_rows(species) %>% 
  full_join(df2, on = "state") %>%
  filter(species == special_species) %>%
  group_by(state, group) %>%
  summarise(species = paste(special_species, collapse = ", "))
#> Joining, by = "state"
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#> # Groups:   state [3]
#>   state group species            
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr>              
#> 1 CA        1 cat                
#> 2 CA        2 cat, chicken, mouse
#> 3 NV        1 dog                
#> 4 WA        1 chicken            
#> 5 WA        2 cat                
#> 6 WA        3 chicken            
#> 7 WA        4 cat, chicken
```

<sup>Created on 2019-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `data.table` implementation that defines a function to find matches row by row. There's probably a more efficient solution to this problem, but here's one possibility:

```
# Import the data.table package
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.frame(state = c("CA", "CA", "NV", "NV", "WA", "WA", "WA", "WA"), group = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4), species = c("cat, dog, chicken, mouse", "cat", "dog, chicken", "chicken", "chicken, rat, mouse, lion", "dog, cat", "dog, chicken", "cat, chicken"))
df2 <- data.frame(state = c("CA", "CA", "CA", "WA", "WA", "NV"), special_species = c("cat", "chicken", "mouse", "cat", "chicken", "dog"))

# Convertint to data table
df1 <- as.data.table(df1)
df2 <- as.data.table(df2)

# Create a function to find matches and return the relevant species
# Steps through df1 row by row
fn_find_matches <- function(sel_row){
  # Get the relevant row information
  comp_row <- df1[sel_row]
  species <- trimws(unlist(strsplit(as.vector(comp_row$species), ",")))

  # Retrieve the relevant df2 information for the state
  comp_tbl <- df2[state == comp_row$state]
  species <- species[species %in% comp_tbl$special_species]

  # If there are no mathcing species, return NA
  if(length(species > 0)){
    comp_row$species <- paste(species, collapse = ", ")
  } else {
    comp_row$species <- NA
  }
  return(comp_row)

}
# Create a resulting table
result_table <- rbindlist(lapply(c(1:nrow(df1)), fn_find_matches))
# Convert back to data frame if desired
setDF(result_table)
setDF(df1)
setDF(df2)
```

Comment: Glad to see I wasn't the only one who found this non-trivial.

Comment: There may be a way to use `merge` to accomplish this, but I'm just not sure off the top of my head. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is based on MSR's answer. We can use `semi_join` to simplify the code.

```
library(tidyverse)

df3 <- df1 %>%
  separate_rows(species) %>%
  semi_join(df2, by = c("state", "species" = "special_species")) %>%
  group_by(state, group) %>%
  summarize(species = toString(species)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(state, group = full_seq(group, period = 1)) %>%
  semi_join(df1, by = c("state", "group"))
df3
# # A tibble: 8 x 3
#   state group species            
#   <chr> <dbl> <chr>              
# 1 CA        1 cat                
# 2 CA        2 cat, chicken, mouse
# 3 NV        1 dog                
# 4 NV        2 NA                 
# 5 WA        1 chicken            
# 6 WA        2 cat                
# 7 WA        3 chicken            
# 8 WA        4 cat, chicken
```

**DATA**

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tribble(
  ~state, ~group, ~species,
  "CA", 2, "cat, dog, chicken, mouse",
  "CA", 1, "cat",
  "NV", 1, "dog, chicken",
  "NV", 2, "chicken",
  "WA", 1, "chicken, rat, mouse, lion",
  "WA", 2, "dog, cat",
  "WA", 3, "dog, chicken",
  "WA", 4, "cat, chicken")

df2 <- tribble(
  ~state, ~special_species,
  "CA", "cat",
  "CA", "chicken",
  "CA", "mouse",
  "WA", "cat",
  "WA", "chicken",
  "NV", "dog")
```